# How to delete all hidden files after execution a program

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse for linux from eclipse.org. I don't really know yet, whether I've started a program properly or nor, but i just unpacked a tar.gz and clicked "eclipse" execution file. It has started and worked properly, before I' ve decided to change the version, so I just deleted unzipped folder, cause I've executed eclipse from it, downloaded a new version of eclipse and repeated the same with a new file. Unfortunately it works properly no more, eclipse will be started, but I see an icon of former version (java EE IDE instead of just Eclipse) of eclipse, Marketplace will be not opened, cannot install a new Software and so on... I believe, there are any hidden files, as config or something else, which embarrassing a using of other versions of eclipse, which were executed previously. I also deleted an .eclipse from root/, but have no any improvements. Are any methods, to delete all files from previous executions of eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

To find files you could run 'locate eclipse'. Also try 'which eclipse' to make sure you're running what you think you are. If you're not running the program as root, deleting .eclipse from /root will probably have no effect. I assume you've looked at your normal user's home diretory with 'ls -a'?

Comment: yes, you are right, i've deleted .eclipse/ as not a root. 'which eclipse' give me no any info (eclipse is running). 'locate eclipse' shows by the way location in .p2/, and app-info/ icons/